# Return String from a webmethod instead of a dataset.

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

How would I refactor this to get it to return a string not a dataset?

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet GetPONumber(string Database)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();

    sqlConn.ConnectionString = GetConnString(Database);

    // build query
    string strSQL = @" A SELECT QUERY!!!!! ";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, sqlConn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "NEWPO");

    return (ds);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I finnished with and is working, thank you for your input:

```
[WebMethod]
    public String GetPONumber(string Database)
    {   
        //Create Object ready for Value
        object po = "";

        //Set Connection
        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnString(Database));

        //Open Connection
        Connection.Open();

        //Set Query to string
        string Query = @" SQL QUERY GOES HERE!!!! ";

        //Run Query
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);

        //Set Value from Query
        try
        {
            po = Command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch
        {
            //Error
        }

        //Clean up sql
        Command.Dispose();
        Command = null;


        //Clean up connection
        Connection.Close();
        Connection.Dispose();
        Connection = null;

        //Return Value
        return po.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could transform the dataset into its JSON string representation. This way it can be easily consumed by basically any client.

Answer (score 1):

You could return ds.GetXml() and change the return type.

That would return the data as XML.

If your results were quite simple (Say a single value), you might just want to return them directly.

Comment: The value in this case is only one single value being returned, Could you show a full example?

Comment: This should work: ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
Although I suggest you use a stored procedure, and use an output parameter, to return the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Use an SqlCommand and the ExecuteScalar method.
//Cast returnValue to known object.
SqlCommand command = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = @" A SELECT QUERY!!!!! ";
sqlConn.Open();
object returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
command.Dispose();
return returnValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

@MartGrif

I have modified your code to include the using statement, this is common usage. It also makes the code more terse and I believe, more readable. The using statement automatically disposes of object at the end of the code block. See documentation on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

```
[WebMethod]
public String GetPONumber(string Database)
{   
    //Create Object ready for Value
    object po = "";

    //Set Connection
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnString(Database)))
    {
        string Query = @" SQL QUERY GOES HERE!!!! ";
        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                po = Command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch
            {
                //Error
            }
        }
    }
    return po.ToString();
}
```